# TransformBlock never completes

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm trying to wrap my head around "completion" in TPL Dataflow blocks. In particular, the `TransformBlock` doesn't seem to ever complete. Why?

### Sample program

My code calculates the square of all integers from 1 to 1000. I used a `BufferBlock` and a `TransformBlock` for that. Later in my code, I await completion of the `TransformBlock`. The block never actually completes though, and I don't understand why.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<int>();
    var calculatorBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating {0}²", i);
        return (int)Math.Pow(i, 2);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 });

    using (bufferBlock.LinkTo(calculatorBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
    {
        foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(1, 1000))
        {
            bufferBlock.Post(number);
        }

        bufferBlock.Complete();

        // This line never completes
        calculatorBlock.Completion.Wait();

        // Unreachable code
        IList<int> results;
        if (calculatorBlock.TryReceiveAll(out results))
        {
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("x² = {0}", result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought I created a deadlock situation, but that doesn't seem to be true. When I inspected the `calculatorBlock.Completion` task in the debugger, its `Status` property was set to `WaitingForActivation`. That was the moment when my brain blue screened.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason your pipeline hangs is that both `BufferBlock` and `TransformBlock` evidently don't complete until they emptied themselves of items (I guess that the desired behavior of `IPropagatorBlock`s although I haven't found documentation on it).

This can be verified with a more minimal example:

```
var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<int>();
bufferBlock.Post(0);
bufferBlock.Complete();
bufferBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

This blocks indefinitely unless you add `bufferBlock.Receive();` before completing.

If you remove the items from your pipeline before blocking by either your `TryReceiveAll` code block, connecting another `ActionBlock` to the pipeline, converting your `TransformBlock` to an `ActionBlock` or any other way this will no longer block.

---

About your specific solution, it seems that you don't need a `BufferBlock` or `TransformBlock` at all since blocks have an input queue for themselves and you don't use the return value of the `TransformBlock`. This could be achieved with just an `ActionBlock`:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<int>(
    i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating {0}²", i);
        Console.WriteLine("x² = {0}", (int)Math.Pow(i, 2));
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8});
foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(1, 1000))
{
    block.Post(number);
}
block.Complete();
block.Completion.Wait();
```

Comment: The documentation only had this to say: _After Complete has been called on a dataflow block, that block will complete, and its Completion task will enter a final state after it has processed all previously available data._

I assumed that "processed" meant "transformed". I would never have guessed that it meant "transformed and received".

Comment: @StevenLiekens I was quite surprised by that myself. I've been testing `BufferBlock` and looking at the source code since you asked this question.

Answer (score 13):

I *think* I understand it now. An instance of `TransformBlock` is not considered "complete" until the following conditions are met:

1. `TransformBlock.Complete()` has been called
2. `InputCount == 0` – the block has applied its transformation to every incoming element
3. `OutputCount == 0` – all transformed elements have left the output buffer

In my program, there is no target block that is linked to the source `TransformBlock`, so the source block never gets to flush its output buffer.

As a workaround, I added a second `BufferBlock` that is used to store transformed elements.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var inputBufferBlock = new BufferBlock<int>();
    var calculatorBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating {0}²", i);
        return (int)Math.Pow(i, 2);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 });
    var outputBufferBlock = new BufferBlock<int>();
    using (inputBufferBlock.LinkTo(calculatorBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
    using (calculatorBlock.LinkTo(outputBufferBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }))
    {
        foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(1, 1000))
        {
            inputBufferBlock.Post(number);
        }

        inputBufferBlock.Complete();
        calculatorBlock.Completion.Wait();

        IList<int> results;
        if (outputBufferBlock.TryReceiveAll(out results))
        {
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("x² = {0}", result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TransformBlock needs a ITargetBlock where he can post the transformation.

```
 var writeCustomerBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(c => Console.WriteLine(c));
        transformBlock.LinkTo(
            writeCustomerBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions
            {
                PropagateCompletion = true
            });
```

After this it completes.